# Insert multiple entries into table using procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a procedure in mysql to insert into table as below.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE createOrderPR ( IN iv_productID INT,
                                 IN iv_orderDate DATE,
                                 IN iv_orderTime TIME,
                                 IN iv_shopID INT,
                                 IN iv_mobileNo varchar(10),
                                 IN iv_quantity smallint,
                                 IN iv_total float(10,2),
                                 IN iv_discount float(10,2),
                                 IN iv_taxable float(10,2),
                                 IN iv_CGST float(10,2),
                                 IN iv_SGST float(10,2)
                                 ) 
                               
 BEGIN
    DECLARE availQty smallint default 0;
    SELECT stockCount INTO availQty FROM product  WHERE productID = iv_productID; 
    SET availQty = availQty - iv_quantity;
    start transaction;
    set autocommit =0;
    INSERT INTO orders(orderNo,productID,orderDate,orderTime,shopID,mobileNo,quantity,total,discount,taxable,CGST,SGST,orderStatus,deletionMark)
    VALUES( null,iv_productID,iv_orderDate,iv_orderTime,iv_shopID,iv_mobileNo,iv_quantity,iv_total,iv_discount,iv_taxable,iv_CGST,iv_SGST,'Open',null); 
    
    UPDATE product SET stockCount = availQty WHERE productID = iv_productID;
    COMMIT;

    SELECT MAX(orderNo) FROM orders  WHERE shopID = shopID AND mobileNo = mobileNo; 
 END
$$
```

Currently it will only allow single record.now I need to insert multiple records in that case how to define the **IN** parameter of the procedure. Please suggest.

Comment: Why not call stored procedure multiple times

Comment: Hi Slava, If call stored procedure multiple time and if one call failed due to some reason then it will create data inconsistent.

Comment: Pass arrays of parameters (for example, as JSON arrays) instead of scalar parameters, parse them and insert multiple rows - what a problem?

Comment: PS. The best way is in storing your data array into temporary table and insert all rows in one query (which cannot be executed partially).

Comment: Hi Akina,you mean to say pass the json array as varchar in the IN parameter ?? Cloud you provide some hints

Comment: Why varchar? JSON is a datatype supported by MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html

Comment: Thanks Akina for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by using the JSON IN parameter these are the sample code (Note:new column added in the table rest all no change)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE createOrderMulti ( IN orderJson JSON,
                                    IN length INT ) 
 BEGIN
    -- Date Declaration
    DECLARE availQty smallint default 0;
    DECLARE iv_productID INT;
    DECLARE iv_orderDate DATE;
    DECLARE iv_orderTime TIME;
    DECLARE iv_shopID INT;
    DECLARE iv_mobileNo varchar(10);
    DECLARE iv_quantity smallint;
    DECLARE iv_total float(10,2);
    DECLARE iv_discount float(10,2);
    DECLARE iv_taxable float(10,2);
    DECLARE iv_CGST float(10,2);
    DECLARE iv_SGST float(10,2);
    DECLARE counter smallint default 0;
    DECLARE item INT;
    DECLARE orderNo INT DEFAULT null;
    
    start transaction;
    set autocommit = 0;
    
    WHILE counter < length DO
    -- Extract the JSON value
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].productID')) INTO iv_productID;
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].orderDate')) INTO iv_orderDate;
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].orderTime')) INTO iv_orderTime;
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].shopID')) INTO iv_shopID;
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].mobileNo')) INTO iv_mobileNo;
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].quantity')) INTO iv_quantity;
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].total')) INTO iv_total;
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].discount')) INTO iv_discount;
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].taxable')) INTO iv_taxable;
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].CGST')) INTO iv_CGST;
    SELECT JSON_VALUE(orderJson, CONCAT('$[', counter, '].SGST')) INTO iv_SGST;
    
    SELECT stockCount INTO availQty FROM product  WHERE productID = iv_productID; 
    SET availQty = availQty - iv_quantity;
    SET item = counter + 1;
    
    INSERT INTO orders(orderNo,item,productID,orderDate,orderTime,shopID,mobileNo,quantity,total,discount,taxable,CGST,SGST,orderStatus,deletionMark)
    VALUES( orderNo,item,iv_productID,iv_orderDate,iv_orderTime,iv_shopID,iv_mobileNo,iv_quantity,iv_total,iv_discount,iv_taxable,iv_CGST,iv_SGST,'Open',null); 
    
    SET orderNo = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    
    UPDATE product SET stockCount = availQty WHERE productID = iv_productID;
    
    SET counter = counter + 1;
    END WHILE;
    COMMIT;
    --SELECT MAX(orderNo) FROM orders  WHERE shopID = shopID AND mobileNo = mobileNo; 
    SELECT orderNo as orderNo;
 END
$$
```